# How do I change the Unity icon color background?

Tags: unity, 12.04, icons, desktop-background, colors

Basically I want to change the light grey background of rhthmbox unity icon by a light green one or another color. Well the idea is to find a tweak to operate for each app background light color. So... is there some way to do do that?

Answer (score 1):

The background colour for each icon is determined by the average colour of the icon so if you use a different icon theme the background colours will change.